Assembly.LoadFile throws if calling app is AOT published in net8
The code is super simple:
var r = Assembly.LoadFile("c:\assembly.dll");
If I publish without <PublishAot>true</PublishAot> - it works. If I publish with <PublishAot>true</PublishAot> - it throws the following exception:
Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at Internal.Reflection.Execution.AssemblyBinderImplementation.Bind(String, AssemblyBindResult&, Exception&) + 0x34
   at System.Reflection.Runtime.Assemblies.RuntimeAssemblyInfo.GetRuntimeAssemblyFromPath(String) + 0x4c
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(String) + 0x6d
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(String) + 0x12c
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) + 0x24
   at app!<BaseAddress>+0x11b1c0

Is there any way to have my app AOT compiled, but have an ability to load custom assemblies and extract code from them?

Limitations of Native AOT deployment
Native AOT apps have the following limitations:

No dynamic loading, for example, Assembly.LoadFile.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=windows%2Cnet8
